# Redis Sorted Sets: How do I get the first intersecting element?

Tags: redis

I have a number of large sorted sets (5m-25m) in Redis and I want to get the first element that appears in a combination of those sets. 
e.g I have 20 sets and wanted to take set 1, 5, 7 and 12 and get only the first intersection of only those sets.

It would seem that a ZINTERSTORE followed by a "ZRANGE foo 0 0" would be doing a lot more work that I require as it would calculate **all** the intersections then return the first one. Is there an alternative solution that does not need to calculate all the intersections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct, native alternative, although I'd suggest this:

Create a **hash** which its members are your elements. Upon each addition to one of your sorted sets, increment the relevant member (using `HINCRBY`). Of course, you'll make the increment only after you check that the element does not exist already in the sorted set you are attempting to add to.

That way, you can quickly know which elements appear in 4 sets.

**UPDATE:** Now that I rethink about it, it might be too expensive to query your hash to find items with value of 4 (*O(n)*). Another option would be creating another Sorted Set, which its members are your elements, and their score gets incremented (as I described before, but using [`ZINCRBY`](http://redis.io/commands/zincrby)), and you can quickly pull all elements with score 4 (using [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore)).

Comment: Thanks Ofer, I didn't really express myself very clearly in my question. The 4 sets are any four sets from a collection of sets... So I may have 20 sets, but during a given query I wan't to take any 2,3 or 4 of them and get the first intersection. I will amend my question.

Comment: Well, in that case I can't think of a workaround to Redis' built-in operations on sets... let's see if another user will come up with an idea. I'm following...

Comment: I ended up having enough cores to split the sets up into very manageable chunks  (and there where far more than I originally assumed) over multiple instances of Redis then reducing over the results from all the shards. I also went on the find that keeping the full set of intersections around for a while gave a performance advantage as it was akin to caching.